# What is this printing error and how can it be fixed?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, monoprice-maker-select

I am not sure what this error is called but would like to learn how to correct it. There is an error at the very top of the print, and then the lower layers at the bottom of the top section.

Printing one of the [Low poly tree sculptures](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:845449) from Thingiverse and had no issues with it until I got to the top section of the tree (see photos).

Using:

- Maker Select V2
- Atomic PLA
- Temp 200 °C / 60 °C
- 20 % Infill
- Print speed 50 mm/s

[image: Upclose photo of an error on printed model]

[image: Top of model showing printing error]

Comment: Just a guess (so only a comment), but looks like inadequate cooling.

Comment: Inadequate cooling would be my first guess, but possibly also the slicer didn't put enough support under those top layers.  The bottom layers might be unsupported overhang as well.

Comment: In regards to the cooling I am going to print and install that shroud fan mod for the V2 and give that a try. Are there any settings in Cura I could look at to increase the support of those top layers? I am not very aware of infill/support configs...

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like inadequate cooling as others suggested. A important aspect to consider is how long the printer spends on a single layer in the trubble areas and how big that area is. The faster a given layer the less time it has to cool. The smaller that area more time the hot nozzle spends in that vicinity heating the surrounding already printed plastic.

Some simple options to fix the issue:

1. If it's adjustable make sure part cooling is enabled by the slicer and that it's at the maximum fan speed at the issue areas.
2. Print additional parts to lengthen the print time at the troublesome Z heights.
3. Slow the print speed. However this can backfire if its too slow as the hot nozzle will remain in the same area for even longer and some extruders can jam if the flow of cool plastic is too low, causing heat to climb past the heat break.
4. Add a external fan to the increase flow of fresh cool air to the area.
5. Reduce nozzle temperature. Can be combined with slower speed as a slower flow rate of plastic can reduce the minimum required print temperature.
6. Add perimeter loops to the print to increase print time. This might not be as effective for a small area as it only adds more heat in a localized area.

A more permanent solution would be to improve the cooling by modifying the ducting or fans. However do be weary of untested fancy fan shrouds reported to improve the air flow as it is easy to make it worse then it was.